# How to change a rectangle roi into a polygon inside an image 480x600 in python?

Tags: python

### I created a rectangle roi in the image but I need to do polygon

### instead.

### Below the code of how I did the rectangle roi

##Define the axis

```
    lower=150
    upper=200
    left= 180
    right=400
```

### how to manipulate these to make a polygon

##Set constraints

```
    if lower >= upper:

       raise ValueError("ROI lower bound must be smaller than upper bound")

   if left >= right:

        raise ValueError("ROI left bound must be smaller than right bound")
```

##Create an image:

```
   image = np.zeros (cleaned.shape, dtype=cleaned.type)
```

Comment: @9769953 I am trying to change the rectangle into polygon. I tried to manipulate the lower, upper.. values with combine function but nothing works. Just need some guidelines what I miss and what I need to do for creating a polygon of roi. My codes work well but it creates a rectangle

Comment: @9769953 Thank you for this. roi is Region of interest. Sorry, I did not get what you mentioned. What I need to set coordinates for a polygon without using the function of polygon as I did with the rectangle?